# Replicate data from couchbase onpremise to AWS documentdb

Tags: mongodb, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway, aws-documentdb

I have a couchbase installation onpremise and the same data at real time needs to be replicated to AWS Document DB, what are the possible approaches?

Can Synch Gateway help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Couchbase's Kafka connector for that (https://github.com/couchbase/kafka-connect-couchbase). Basically, it allows you to listen to all document changes in CB and push it to third party systems.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am thinking of creating Lambda to consume events from Kafka and pushing it to document DB. Is it a good approach?

Comment: Also, it would be nice if you can provide me an example of how to use AWS Lambda as a Kafka consumer

Comment: @sam this seems like it would do as an example: https://github.com/llofberg/kafka-connect-aws-lambda or just scheduling a lambda to iteratively consume anything new in MSK since the previous connection. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html